# Independent Events in Probability and Two dimensional random variable

Tags: probability, independence

I am trying to solve this problem, and get an answer I am not sure about.
"On his way to work, Mr. Smith passes 3 traffic lights. The probability of green light is 0.6 in each traffic light, independently with the other two. X is defined as the number of traffic lights that Mr Smith came to in green light, until he stopped on red light for the first time (not including the first red light), or until he arrived to his destination (there was no red light). Y is defined as the number of red lights, from the first red light and until green light (not including a green light) or until arrival to his destination. Calculate P(X=1, Y=2)."

How do you think this should be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly P(X=1,Y=2) means that he hit one green light, then two red lights.

Ignoring yellow lights, if P(green) = 0.6, then P(red) = 0.4

Since all are independent of one another, P(X=1,Y=2) = P(green, red, red) = P(green) * P(red) * P(red) = 0.6 * 0.4 * 0.4 = 0.0960 or 9.6%

Comment: This is exactly how I understood it and this is the answer I got. However the given answer was different, probably a mistake, but I wasn't sure. Now that someone else got the same, I am sure. Thanks a lot !!